# How to make keyboard move along with scrollview?

Tags: ios, scroll, searchbar

I have a scrollview and a searchbar in a controller. And I want the keyboard move along with the scrollview when the scrollview is being dragged. Just as when edit a message on iphone.

So what should I do and I will appreciate it if you can give me some code.

What I mean is when the searchbar is the first responder,there will be a keyboard ha ?

And if I scroll the scrollview ,the keyboard will move along with it.

Some one said I should listen some notification. Is it right?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've never had the keyboard move along with any scroll view when I dragged it on the phone... so I'm not sure what you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: Can you explain what is the need for scrolling the keyboard?...

Comment: When you use your iphone to send message you can find out that if you scroll the content of discuss, the keyboard will move along with your finger.

Comment: You mean how you can dismiss with a fast swipe gesture?

Comment: I didn't mean that. I mean how to make the keyboard move?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move a keyboard along with the view.You can only change position of the view underneath it.Therefore, If you wish to move the keyboard along with the scroll....All You need to do is to make your own custom keyboard!!!!!

Comment: But how can I make my custom keyboard. The searchbar.inputAccessoryView is keyboard belongs to searchbar. If I change the frame of it, I can move the keyboard?

Comment: There's no need to make a custom keyboard , neither you can move your keyboard.....what you have to do is just change the postion of the view underneath it......

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1

Comment: Why don't you understand that you cannot move the keyboard.Instead move the view.

Comment: When I use my Iphone to send message I can move the keyboard man. Trust me!